# python count files and display max

Tags: python, count

I am tying to count al file extenties in a directory. And then count them and display how many of them are there. What is the best way to make this? This script gonna be really big with al the `pdf= 0` lines of code.
Also how can I display the output of how many files there are, from high to lower.

```
import os

pdf = 0
doc = 0
docx = 0
xls = 0
xlsx = 0
ppt = 0
pptx = 0

for file in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH"):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".doc"):
        doc += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        docx += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".xls"):
        xls += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        xlsx += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".ppt"):
        ppt += 1
        print(file)
    if file.endswith(".pptx"):
        pptx += 1
        print(file)

print(pdf)
print(doc)
print(docx)
```

Comment: use a dictionary. that will allow you to remove all the code duplication (which is the root of all evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dictionary:

```
import os

exts = {}
my_exts = ('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx')

for file in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH"):
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext and ext[1:] in my_exts:
        exts[ext] = exts.get(ext, 0) + 1

print sorted(exts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

The output will be:

`[('.doc', 4), ('.pdf', 2), ('.xlsx', 1)]`

Comment: Hmm I don't know what I was thinking about, but apparently I wasn't thinking very hard!

Answer (score 6):

This is where you'd use a `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os.path

d = defaultdict(int)

for fname in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH"):
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    d[ext] += 1
```

Then you'll end up with a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'.pdf': 7,  # or however many...
 '.doc': 3,
 '.docx': 2, ...}
```

You can then display the most common by doing:

```
max(d, key=lambda k: d[k])
```

Comment: Hi @joey. The code block up top populates `d` to look like the second code block (for whatever actual values you have). You can then manipulate the dictionary however you like. You're not clear in your question how you want to use the data.

Comment: @AdamSmith Hey Thanks for helping me! I got it working now thanks a lot:)
I have to make a script that detect files and displays how many of them there are

Comment: if you want to print them all from most- to least-common, try something like https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/f7a3c8a5d8837f12faba

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the filenames with the those format then use `collections.Counter` :

```
from colections import Counter
import re
print Counter([re.sub(r'.*\.(\w+'),r'\1',i) for i in  os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH")]
```

Or as @Adam Smith mentioned you can use `os.path.splitext(i)[1]` instead of `re.sub`:

```
print Counter([os.path.splitext(i)[1] for i in  os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH")]
```

And for displaying from high to lower you can use `most_common` method :

```
count=Counter([re.sub(r'.*\.(\w+'),r'\1',i) for i in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joey\\Desktop\\school\\ICOMMH")]
for i, j in count.most_common():
       print i,j
```

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah its more pythonic! thank for mentioning that!

Answer (score 2):

Using `splitext` and `Counter` and its `most_common` since you said you want from high to low.

```
import os, collections
extensions = (os.path.splitext(f)[1] for f in os.listdir())
for ext, cnt in collections.Counter(extensions).most_common():
    print(ext, cnt)
```

Prints for example:

```
.txt 33
.csv 12
.py 10
.png 8
 4
.json 2
.class 1
.c 1
.pl 1
.exe 1
.java 1
.sh 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it will be easier if you used "glob" library (link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html). The usage of this library is easy, it is as simple as you send a pattern of the file name and extension, and it will return a list of files within the same directory of the .py file which match the pattern.

Example:

```
import glob;

pdf_files_list = glob.glob("*.pdf"); # star "*" represents wild card.
```

then you can know the number of files by using:

```
len(pdf_files_list); # len is a function that returns the length of a list.
```